# Sudarsana Homam - Timings for conducting

Tags: mantras, tradition, sudarsana, homam

I learnt from pundits and scholars that poornahuthi for sudarsana homam should be put within 12 noon. It takes six hours to perform sudarsana homam. Normally homams should be done from 5 am and finish within 12 noon. [at the max]. But nowadays I observe that the sudarsana homam is being carried out by few people in the evening; starting from 6 pm and ending by 9 pm. If the homam is performed by an individual it will benefir the whole universe. On the other hand if it is done after sunset will it cause retro effect? Presently the whole world is reeling in pandemic. Can this be answered  by appropriate citings?

Note: My company sent an invitation for puja for day after tomorrow.. In that it is mentioned Mahasudarsana Homa starts from 7/30 pm and ends by 10pm?

Comment: ashvameda and other yagna conducted yearly long also, its deemed asupucious based on region you live, andhra prefers night time as there is no rahu, yama, goolikai or ketta kala falling in the night..reference SM Bhagavatam Krishna performed ashvemeda he went vaikuta and came back to complete ashwameda

Comment: @Prasanna  Pl note that homams and yagnas are different. Homam timing I refer to IST.

Comment: homa is short form of yagna Andhra and Karanataka preference is  given in night.. please check the marriage rituals. Yes its asupicios to conduct homam without having food.. other than this only region based difference only i see

Comment: @ prasanna Poornahuthi should be put by noon.